# Error with com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator

Tags: android, gradle, colors, viewpagerindicator

> It worked before, but now it throws:
>
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML
>   file line #17: Error inflating class
>   com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension:
>   type=0x1d`
>
> I've tried to set @color/color_primary values and '#ff00ff' color hex
>   values: the same issue.
>
> As a workaround: I set all needed colors in runtime by calling
>   setFillColor(), setPageColor() and setStrokeColor() respectively.

Library version    `compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'`

Source https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/issues/424

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you update your gradle version, and this Lib isn't giving any support or having updates for more than 5 years...
Despite I tried many other alternatives to keep using it, the best solution was to change it for this one:
implementation 'com.github.splatte:ViewPagerIndicator:3.0.0'

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47785895/6706788
There are other options there (one telling to add "app:" on all attributes of this lib), feel free to try them too if you want, for me, the solution of the alternative lib (a branch) was the only one that worked.