# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 5 to color: type=0x5

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

My app is crashing after updating to `Android Studio 3 RC1` (`Gradle` 4, Android `Gradle` plugin 3 RC2).

```
This is the error I am having:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{*****}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0:
Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:211)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
       at com.raimbekov.android.sajde.zikr.ZikrActivity.onCreate(ZikrActivity.java:195)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 5 to color: type=0x5
    10-20 10:48:09.562 6156-6156 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:473)
        at com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator.<init>(CirclePageIndicator.java:96)
        at com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator.<init>(CirclePageIndicator.java:72)
            ... 34 more
```

I didn't have this problem before update (on `Android Studio` 2). It is also described on [github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/issues/424), but no answer.

Comment: Post your layout file ?

Comment: This code (CirclePageIndicator) has not been updated for 5 years. On API < 21 you can't use attrs to colour in xml drawable. So only way is to use a reference to a colour resource (@color/YOURS_COLOR) or use #RGB format. You will probably have to change: :JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator library.

Comment: @JonGoodwin thank you. I am not using attrs. My colors are defined in styles as RGB and it perfectly works on API 15.

Comment: @Neeraj it works on Android Studio 2 without any problems. Here is a snippet from the layout:

`<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:id="@+id/text_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>`

Comment: `<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                style="@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator"
                android:id="@+id/text_pager_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                app:radius="4dp" />`

Comment: styles.xml:

`<style name="CustomCirclePageIndicator">
  <item name="fillColor">#80333333</item>
  <item name="unselectedColor">#80a9a9a9</item>
  <item name="centered">true</item>
  <item name="strokeColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="pageColor">#80a9a9a9</item>
 </style>`

Answer (score 28):

Change
`compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'`

to
`compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'`

It'll work. There is a problem with the library.

Comment: How does this actually solve it? Didn't work in my case but I wonder what difference it actually makes.

Comment: this is a problem with "compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'" library... it reads an array of colors, and couldn't find a particular index... this bug is fixed in "compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'" library... which library are you using??

Comment: @EmreDirican It didn't work in my case either. I had to replace xml attributes with programmatical settings as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47163075/885464

Answer (score 9):

My project uses android gradle plugin 3.0 and compileSdk 27. I wasn't able to make it work with this setup using the suggested solutions (`compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'`) in this thread.

It was complaining about methods like `ViewPager#removeOnPageChangeListener` not existing which have been added in version 24 of the support library. I think it has to do with the fact that the library has android-support-v4.jar directly baked in.

I didn't want to go through all my xml files and set the attributes programmatically so I ended up creating a fork that uses gradle to build the library and bumps compileSdk/minSdk/support-v4 to more modern versions.

You can find the project here https://github.com/splatte/ViewPagerIndicator

To use it in your project, get it from jitpack like so:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
      maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.splatte:ViewPagerIndicator:3.0.0'
}
```

(There must be another project that does this in the sea of 4.300 forks that ViewPagerIndicator has, but I didn't know how to find it.)

Answer (score 6):

`compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'` using `jitpack.io` didn't work for me with the android gradle plugin 3.0.

Instead I had to set programmatically all the view attributes that I previously set in the xml layout with `cpi:` (or `app:`) attributes.

Example

```xml
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    cpi:fillColor="@color/azure"
    cpi:pageColor="@color/white"
    cpi:radius="4dp"
    cpi:snap="true"
    cpi:strokeWidth="0dp" />
```

I removed all the `cpi:` attributes and set them all programmatically:

```java
circlePageIndicator.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.azure));
circlePageIndicator.setPageColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white));
circlePageIndicator.setRadius((int) (4 * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density));
circlePageIndicator.setSnap(true);
circlePageIndicator.setStrokeWidth(0);
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the `jitpack.io` the easiest method:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
      maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
dependencies {
  implementation ('com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
}
```

Just to note that having two versions of the support-v4 library broke it until I excluded one of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Well the library has not been updated from long time so it so currently creating a lot of problems in updated sdk for that you need to replace the library by below**

///// old library

```
implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
```

// replaced it by below
//for View Pagerindicator

```
implementation 'com.github.splatte:ViewPagerIndicator:3.0.0'
```

**it will work, if not please do not forget to add**

```
   maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

// put it inside the setting.gradle